# Prelude "and" and "or" functions on empty lists

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've just started to play with Haskell using GHCI. The REPL comes with a bunch of built in functions. For example `and` and `or` to reduce boolean lists `[Bool] -> Bool`. It was quite suprising to me that for empty lists it gives:

```
Prelude> and []
True
Prelude> or []
False
```

Are there any good reasons for such a behaviour? I was kinda expecting the opposite results. Even `False` in both cases looks more reasonable to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In both cases, they give the identity element of the operation:

```
True && x == x
False || x == x
```

For each operation, it's the boolean that "does nothing", which makes it the perfect choice to return when you get nothing as an input!

This is the same way that `sum` and `product` start off with `0` and `1` respectively.

Answer (score 7):

This is easier to understand if we talk instead about `all, any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`.  Intuitively:

1. `all p` searches a list to find a **counterexample** to the predicate `p`.  It returns `False` if and only if such a counterexample is found.
2. `any p` searches a list to find an **example** that satisfies the predicate `p`.  It returns `True` if and only if such an example is found.

Therefore:

1. `all p []` is true because the empty list does not contain any counterexamples to `p`.
2. `any p []` is false because the empty list does not contain any examples that satisfy `p`.

Note that:

```
and == all id
or  == any id
```

So this reasoning extends to `and, or :: [Bool] -> Bool`.

Note that mathematical logic often also works like this:

```
-- "All unicorns are Argentinian."
∀x. unicorn(x) → argentinian(x)
```

This proposition is true if unicorns don't exist.  Logic newbies get confused by this as well...

Comment: Thanks. `every` and `any` analogy is quite usefull. I was thinking of those functions as a `fold`. 
Damn, now I don't know whose answer is better :)